# Django Messages do not disappear

Tags: html, django, webbrowser-control, message

I'm facing the issue that on some browsers my Django messages do not disappear. For example, if a new post gets created the side indicates with a message that the new post has been successfully created. If I reload the page the message doesn't disappear and keeps showing up, why is that?

The issue goes so far that messages are stacking after using the side for a while you only see messages xD ...

Can somebody help with this? Is this just because of the browser that is being used?

This is how I display my messages:

```
<div class="messages">
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <span><li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li></span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why it doesn't disappear? You could delete the message in your python file manually. It is simply _NOT_ the browser's fault. Or you can add some JavaScript to `setTimeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

In your template

```
{% for message in messages %}
     {%if "hello" in message.tags %}
          <p class="messages alert alert-success" style="text-align: center;">  {{message}} </p> 
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
messages.warning(request, 'Insert whatever msg you want here.', extra_tags='hello')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this solve the question, from what I see it is completely off topic

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are doing or what the effect is? THanks so far :D

Comment: Hi sure, could you replace your code with mine first to see if it works :)

Comment: @kknam no, your guess is wrong ! The condition will check wether a message is specified in the view, once the page is refresh the message should not be display. With your statement you are making the view unnecessary complicated

Comment: @GaëtanGR I have tested the code and it's correct. Do you have a better alternative to make it less complicated? (I'm assuming he has multiple messages)...If he doesn't, then he can just remove the extra tag and the hello in the template

Comment: The core issues are mobile browsers like Firefox on Android or iOS. On a "normal/PC" browser I dont have this issue at all